# It might be a stupid question but

Tags: phrases

I have read and heard these kinds of sentences or utterances many times:

"It might be a stupid question but can fish breath?"

"I don´t know how to say this but you should change your life!"

I don´t understand how to grammatically analyze this correctly. Are these introductory phrases (and therefore a comma has to follow before, "but"!?) followed by a question or an imperative sentence or is a different kind of thing? I can´t make sense of it otherwise because, "This might be a stupid question" can´t really stand by itself for example, can it?

A further question I have is if you have to pose the question or the imperative statement right after, "but". For example:

"It might be a stupid question but it is a question nonetheless: Do fish breath?"

or even

"It might be a stupid question but it is a question I might not pose otherwise.
Last year I......and then......(a number of sentences might follow).
Do fish breath?"

Comment: "This might be a stupid question" can definitely be a stand-alone question.  I might be ten feet tall.  Today might be rainy.  This might be Uncle John's umbrella.  etc., etc.

Comment: I was talking about these examples in connection with, "but" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are basically correct in your understanding.  I would rewrite these sentences this way to be more explicit:

> This might be a stupid question but I'm going to ask anyway: Do fish breathe?

Note that this is informal speech, also common on the internet, but would not be appropriate in more proper written communication. It's not great grammar.

Comment: I figured that. To me, it´s not grammar at all. I don´t understand how you could pose a question by introducing it like that and then link everything with, "but". So, formally speaking it is incorrect? All of it? I have to teach English one day. That is why I need to know in detail.

Comment: I would not write this on a college essay or on the SAT but it's perfectly normal in speech.